# How to pass inputs from 'Scanner' to my variable of 2 parameters from other class?

Tags: java

I want to execute the 'addition of 2 fractions' code. Below are my code. How do I pass the input from the `Scanner` to my other Fraction variable? Please have a look at my `if (operation.equals("+"))` code. I know how to add the 2 fractions given that I set the values beforehand, but how do I pass the inputs from the scanner to my `addFraction` method with 2 parameters?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class FractionCalculator {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Fraction f = new Fraction(1,2);
    public static Fraction addFrac = new Fraction();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getOperation();
    }
    
    public static String getOperation() {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter an operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String operation = input.nextLine();
    
        if (operation.equals("+")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a fraction (a/b) or integer (a): ");
            int addFrac = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(f.add(addFrac()));
        }
        return getOperation();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    
    Fraction(int num, int den) {
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
    
        if (den == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not possible to use denominator zero");
        } else if (den < 0) {
            numerator = num * -1;
            denominator = den * -1;
        } else {
            this.numerator = num;
            this.denominator = den;
        }
    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction other) {
       Fraction addFraction = new Fraction(((numerator*other.denominator)+(other.numerator*denominator)),(denominator*other.denominator));
        addFraction.toLowestTerms();
        return addFraction;
    }
}
```

Comment: `addFrac` is an `int` (not a `function`). Your method takes a `Fraction`. Not an `int`. You need something like `f.add(new Fraction(addFrac));` I say something like, because you have no constructor that takes one `int`. You need two. Also, you should override `toString` in `Fraction` or you'll have another problem in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read `a/b` using `nextInt()`.  So, my suggestion is you read the fraction as `a/b` as a string and then convert `a` and `b` to integers as below.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a fraction (a/b): ");
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] parts = line.split("/");
int numerator = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int denominator = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
Fraction addFrac = new Fraction(numerator, denominator  ));
```